# Resizing images relative to one another in HTML

Tags: html, css

I need to have 3 images, 1 on the top row and 2 on the bottom row, and they all have to be the same size.

I want all the images to be the same size, with the two bottom images next to each other and the top image centered above them.

I have tried putting the images in a table and using colspan="2" for the top row, but the top image then becomes much larger than the bottom two. I have also tried using colspan="2" for all three images, with the addition of an empty column on either side of the top image, but then the left image on the bottom row is tiny, the right image on the bottom row is huge, and the top image is medium-sized. I removed the links in the code below to make it easier to read.

In the first attempt, the image on top is much larger than the other two (which is expected), but in the second attempt, the image on the bottom right is the largest, the image on the bottom left is tiny, and the image on top is medium-sized.

Comment: A. Welcome! B. Please show us your code (use [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)). C. Can you just set the image as the size you want (e.g. `width` and `height` attributes)?

Answer (score 0):

You could set your image height and width like this:

```
     <img src="path/to/asset" alt="alt title" height="42" width="42">
```

Comment: Without seeing how the OP is actually setting up the HTML/CSS, this answer may not be correct.

Comment: Just a suggestion.

Comment: If its a suggestion, please add this as a comment not as an answer.